# Load Data On Uitableview scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2000 records and i have to display only 15 records in `UITableView`, When User Scroll `UITableView` , More 15 records shold be load in table. How should I do it?

Comment: u want to display only 15 record ???

Comment: Yes, Only first 15 then another 15 on table scroll

Comment: Rather than fixing it to 15 records, get visible cells inside the table and update the data only to those cells. You can get the visible cells information like this:  NSArray *visibleCells = [tableview visibleCells]; Refer to this example for lazyloading: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Why not tell the table up front that it has 2000 rows? What benefit are you expecting by only loading 15 at a time? What happens when the user scrolls the table very quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Answer is : `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    float reload_distance = 15;
    if(y > h + reload_distance)
    {
         //Call the Method to load More Data...
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful...!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the `UIScrollView` `contentOffset` for that (`UITableView` is built on `UIScrollView`). So, add this, to your `UITableViewDelegate` class:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // when reaching bottom, load more

    float offs = (scrollView.contentOffset.y+scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    float val = (scrollView.contentSize.height);
    if (offs==val)
    {
     //add more data on your data array   
    }
}
```

in order to add more cells to your table when user reaches bottom of your table view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two delegate methods of `UIScrollView`. As `UITableView` comes in hierachy of `UIScrollView` you'll get control in this delegate methods of `UIScrollView`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"TableView scrolling");
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"TableView Started scrolling");
}
```

Try above two methods. And choose the one appropriate for you. First see how `NSLog` are coming when you start scrolling your `UITableVIew`. And then write your code inside them.

Answer (score 1):

**By Default numberOfItemsToDisplay = 15;**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        if (numberOfItemsToDisplay >= [self.yourArray count])
        {
            numberOfItemsToDisplay = [self.yourArray count];
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCustomCell";
            YourCustomCell *objYourCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (objYourCustomCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
                {
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[YourCustomCell class]])
                    {
                        objYourCustomCell = (AlertsCustomCell *) currentObject;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            objYourCustomCell.lbl.text = [[self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"vName"];
            return objYourCustomCell;
        }
        else
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {

                cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:[self loadMoreViewForTable:self.view]];
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.tblAlertsList deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            numberOfItemsToDisplay =  [self loadMore:numberOfItemsToDisplay arrayTemp:self.yourArray tblView:self.tblAlertsList];
            [self.tblAlertsList endUpdates];
        }else
        {
           // action if it is not LoadMore
        }
    }

    + (NSInteger)loadMore : (NSInteger)numberOfItemsToDisplay arrayTemp:(NSMutableArray*)aryItems tblView:(UITableView*)tblList
    {
        int count =0;
        NSUInteger i, totalNumberOfItems = [aryItems count];
        NSUInteger newNumberOfItemsToDisplay = MIN(totalNumberOfItems, numberOfItemsToDisplay + kNumberOfItemsToAdd);
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (i=numberOfItemsToDisplay; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay; i++)
        {
            count++;
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
        numberOfItemsToDisplay = newNumberOfItemsToDisplay;
        [tblList beginUpdates];
        [tblList insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        if (numberOfItemsToDisplay == totalNumberOfItems) {
            [tblList deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
        NSIndexPath *scrollPointIndexPath;
        if (newNumberOfItemsToDisplay < totalNumberOfItems)
        {
            scrollPointIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfItemsToDisplay-kNumberOfItemsToAdd inSection:0];
        }
        else
        {
            scrollPointIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i-count inSection:0];
        }
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 100000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [tblList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollPointIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone  animated:YES];
        });
        return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
    }
```

I have to take custom cell to use this method? I have only taken UItableview

Comment: It's not mandatory that you should use only customcell.. you can carry on with your tableView. But make sure you are reusing the cells not creating all the time..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stableviewcontroller

use this two methods

```
//for refresh
- (void) addItemsOnTop {

     //[self getLoginFollowingUserVideosCall];
     [self refreshCompleted];
}

//for load more
- (void) addItemsOnBottom  {

     //[self getLoginFollowingUserVideosCall];
     [self loadMoreCompleted];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is load the tableview data lazily. Like load data for the tableview cell that are current visible & not all of the data at a time.