# UIScrollView scroll up show like pageControl

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView`, on this view, I add more `UIView`, like this

[image]

When I scroll up or down, I want the `UIView` full display, the effect like `UIPageControl`, but I just want change one cell or more, not a page.

How could I do it? Thanks.

**Edit**

The effect like this [here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

But I want use to control all the `UIView`, and scroll up and down just one or more `UIView`.

Comment: Whats wrong with `UITableview` ?

Comment: In my `UIView` have another thing to do, so I use `UIScrollView`

Comment: what you done with UIview you can also do with it.

Comment: If I use `UITableView`. How to achieve this effect? Thanks.

Comment: There are many question realted with tableview make little effort for search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081648/how-to-implement-loading-more-for-table-view-when-scroll-to-bottomi-e-pull-up , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354133/load-data-on-uitableview-scroll, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000255/how-to-add-load-more-page-when-scrolling-to-bottom-of-table

Comment: how about implementing a snap functionality for your tableview?. This is much more useful then the way you are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The answer reference [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342790/685060)

Use `UIScrollView` can achieve this effect.

**Edit**

In order scroll accuracy, I use `fmodf`. This can reference [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271136/685060).

This is my code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float toMove = fmodf(scrollView.contentOffset.y, _cellHeight);

    if(toMove < _cellHeight / 2)
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y - toMove) animated:YES];
    else
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y + (_cellHeight - toMove)) animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    [self scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView];
}
```